# Limit length shown for a url with DisplayFormat annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, string-length

I am trying to limit how many characters of a url is going to be shown with annotations. I want the link be able to be very long it is only how it is displayed that I want to change. I could limit the length in every view that displays the url (Link), but I would prefer to change it only once in the model. I don't understand why this does not work. After adding the DisplayFormat annotation the url is shown as before without the length changing at all.

```
[Required()]
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,20}")]
public string Link { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which methods are you using which you expect to use the DisplayFormat attribute?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor`

After having searched more on the internet I get the impression that maximum length can not be set with DisplayFormat.

I thought that {0,20} would set the length to 20 but I get the impression now that it only sets the 'minimun' length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to achieve it is to create your own template for your data type. One of possible solutions is to add `ShortUrl.asxc` or `ShortUrl.cshtml` to `Shared\DisplayTemplates` folder:

```
@model string

@Model.Substring(20)
```

And then change your field definition to:

```
[Required()]
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,20}")]
[UIHint("ShortUrl")]
public string Link { get; set; }
```

or provide template name in a view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Link, "ShortUrl")
```

Of course you could extend your display template to use metadata and check for nulls etc.,